# My Java Classes giving me errors

Tags: java, opengl

My two LWJGL Classes are giving me error and I'm assuming it's something to do with the cube I've made as it is not showing!

Error: The hierarchy of the type stonehearth_display/stonehearth_cube is inconsistent

stonehearth_display:

```
package com.mime.stonehearth;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class stonehearth_display extends stonehearth_cube{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setTitle("Stonehearth Pre-Alpha 0.0.1");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            System.err.println("Display wasn't initialized correctly.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            render();

            angle = (angle+1)%360;
        }


        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

stonehearth_cube.java

```
package com.mime.stonehearth;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;



public class stonehearth_cube extends stonehearth_display{


        int angle = 0 ;

    public void render(){

        float edgeLength= 20.0f;
        edgeLength /= 2.0f;

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0f, Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth(), Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight(), 0.0f, -50.0f, 50.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //clear screen
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef((Display.getWidth()/2), (Display.getHeight()/2), 0.0f);
        glRotatef(angle, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

        //Back

        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-edgeLength, edgeLength, edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(-edgeLength, -edgeLength, edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, -edgeLength, edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(-edgeLength, edgeLength, edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, edgeLength, edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, -edgeLength, edgeLength);

        //Front

        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-edgeLength, edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(-edgeLength, -edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, -edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(-edgeLength, edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, -edgeLength, -edgeLength);

        // Right
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, -edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, -edgeLength, edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, edgeLength, -edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, edgeLength, edgeLength);
        glVertex3f(edgeLength, -edgeLength, edgeLength);

        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You have a circular class inheritance. How does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have classes inherited by himself or her childclass.

stone_cube --> stone_display --> stone_cube --> stone_display...

Do you catch it?

I thing you only have to inherite stone_cube from stone_display, after, you must create another where create one stone_display or one stone_cube and do stuff.